# Can I implement Splash screen in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, splash-screen

The main activity is a login page. I have included a splash screen as well. What I want is to apply animation to the splash screen. For that, I am trying to put it in a separate fragment. How can I do this?

I have created a theme and everything that is needed to implement a basic splash screen.

Comment: you need to set animation for splash or another things?

Comment: You should but why are you not go with activity?

Comment: i need to set animations for splash as well as other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the apps(youtube, facebook etc) don't have an animated splash screen because, all the code initialization drops a lot of frames in your app. These frame drops will be clearly visible if you try to animate the screen.

For your animations to be smooth, a frame has to be drawn every 16ms. Even if one frame is not drawn, users can see the change... what this means is, if you are jumping a ball on ur splash screens.. the easing function you apply to the animation will not work as expected.

Solution:
   In your launcher activity, just have a simple ui. As minimal as possible. This will give the user a feeling that app launched quickly. Once your initializations are over, you can attach your fragment which can have the same UI as activity and then make any transition.

---

In practice:

Launch activity A(launcher) -> UI can be a simple white screen with your logo in the center of the screen.

Once your initialization(all the libraries that load in your Application class like firebase, ORM, analytics tools ect) is over, attach your fragment with a screen containing the same white screen and logo.

This way the user will not know transition from activity to ur fragment as the UI is same. Now you can do any kind of animation in your screen. The initialization time varies from application to application and phone to phone.

Comment: could you please elaborate your solution?

Comment: so i need to make two screens that are basically the same, one is a splash while other is a regular fragment(which will be displayed after the splash) and i can perform animations on the fragment?